# Open Modal Dialog Inside SharePoint Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I have a SharePoint hosted app, and I am trying to open the new item form of a SharePoint list on host web in a modal dialog using SP.UI.ModalDialog. The dialog opens fine, but when I click save or cancel I get the following error. I think this related to cross site scripting. Does anyone know of a way to open list forms in a dialog from a app?

"Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'frame' property from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin http://hostweb.test.com from accessing a frame with origin http://app-c959f429388742.app.test.com. Protocols, domains, and ports must match.".

Thanks,